# C# Selenium bot element selection trouble

Tags: c#, selenium, console-application

I am trying to make a bot that goes through drop-downs and makes selections but it's having trouble finding the element. The code is below.

```
 using System;
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

 namespace selenium_test
 {
      class Program
      {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               IWebDriver driver;

               driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\");

               Console.WriteLine("ChromeDriver Initialized");

               driver.Url = "https://odyssey.gwinnettcourts.com/Portal/Home/Dashboard/26";

               IWebElement typeElement =                 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//option[@id='cboHSSearchBy']"));
               var typeSelect = new SelectElement(typeElement);
               typeSelect.SelectByValue("JudicialOfficer");

               typeElement.Click();
         } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly is the error? I can only assume that it is taking time to find element.
add wait time maybe? also, why using xpath when you have id of controls? id is quicker!

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id("cboHSSearchBy"))));